# unassigned_shards how to solve it

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?level=shards'

{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 1486,
  "active_shards" : 1486,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 1486,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 50.0
}
```

How to solve unassigned shards  and active_shards_percent_as_number

** Am using ES 2.4 latest **

thanking you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simply because you have a single node in your cluster but all your indices are configured to have one replica per shard (the default setting).

If you run the following command you'll get rid of the replicas and your cluster will turn green:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_settings' -d '{
    "index" : {
        "number_of_replicas" : 0
    }
}'
```

Comment: For every newly created index in ES. we need to hit the curl command @val

Comment: You can also configure that as default in `elasticsearch.yml`

Comment: This configuration forced elasticsearch to save everything on primary shards and solved my problem.